# How can you run a function exactly when the user clicks an element?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, usually you use `selector.addEventListener('click', function)` to run a function when the use clicks and then lets go of an element. How can I run a function just when the user clicks, and hasn't yet let go?

Thanks in advance,
Tilier

Comment: You're looking for the `onmousedown` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `mousedown` and `mouseup` events for what you want

```
selector.addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>{...});
```

Comment: Hmm . . . it's not working for me. Let me try again.

Comment: @Tilier  check the code again, i had misspelled `onmousedown`

Comment: Yeah, this is wrong. It's `mousedown`, not `onmousedown`. `onmousedown` is for in HTML.